# WooCommerce Cart Widget - Change button Text

Tags: html, css

Hey Guys so i am trying to edit the text in the woocommerce cart widget?
I have successfully changed the button layout, but need to edit the text in the buttons.
I have limited CSS knowledge at the moment so any help would be great!

[CartWidget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkiHt.jpg)

Comment: where is code for `cart button`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure...